# New Interface Builder (Xcode 6) removes rect and kills design

Tags: xcode6, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Hello fellow programers,

After updating to Xcode6, any change to the storyboard in interface builder, removes all xml-nodes being  ... this results in some elements not been shown anymore (for me at least). Just merging the changed part in to the storyboard xml containing the rects and not opening interface builder, but compiling the source straight away, it all runs smoothly.

I do not understand what this change does - nor how to fix this. Any ideas?

small code excerpt:

```
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6Xn-x2-5go" userLabel="categoryDeletedButton">
  <rect key="frame" x="33" y="-7" width="48" height="48"/>
```

The rect line ist the one being removed by the new interface builder. Everywhere in the storyboard XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright: new IB **requires** constraints and removes rects, if they are not available. Before editing any elements dimensions, add constrains - save, resize anything and observe if more elements vanish from the storyboard (undo and add constraints for that vanished elem too).